# Show only title (with linked) on tumblr index

Tags: tumblr

I'm looking for a way to only show posts titles (with link) on my tumblr index, and then show the entire post when you click.

I know about the "cut" function, but i want to simple hide the whole content on the index page only.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is Stackoverflow related (since you didn't paste any code). Try [Webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) if you'd like an answer.

Comment: it's HTML related: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes - i want something like {block:!IndexPage} or {block:NotIndexPage}, since the post block display by default on both cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `{block:IndexPage}` to show the post titles and `{block:PermalinkPage}` to show all of the content.

Unfortunately, only three Tumblr post types support titles: Text, Chat and Link.